# Driving route ios7 in India

Tags: ios7

I need to show a driving route in iOS 7. I know we can use `MKDirections` for this purpose, but the problem is Apple Maps will not showing driving routes in India. When I Googled I have found if Google Maps is installed on an iPhone device we can use it show directions, otherwise we can't show
directions. Can we use Google Maps in iOS? Do Apple allow to use google map in iOS 7.

Below is the code which i used:

```
MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.776142, -122.424774)
    addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];
// MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.00145, 76.2828)
    addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

MKMapItem *srcMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
[srcMapItem setName:@""];

MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.73787, -122.373962)
    addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];
//  MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(9.950012, 76.349988)
    addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

MKMapItem *distMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
[distMapItem setName:@""];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
[request setSource:srcMapItem];
[request setDestination:distMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeWalking];

MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"response = %@",response);
    NSArray *arrRoutes = [response routes];
    [arrRoutes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        MKRoute *rout = obj;

        MKPolyline *line = [rout polyline];
        [self.mkMapView addOverlay:line];
        NSLog(@"Rout Name : %@",rout.name);
        NSLog(@"Total Distance (in Meters) :%f",rout.distance);

        NSArray *steps = [rout steps];

        //NSLog(@"Total Steps : %d",[steps count]);

        [steps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"Rout Instruction : %@",[obj instructions]);
            NSLog(@"Rout Distance : %f",[obj distance]);
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps easily take a webview and parse the string given below

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

self.locationController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
self.locationController.delegate = self;
[self.locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

- (void)update:(CLLocation *)location {
    self.lblLatitude.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude  %f", [location coordinate].latitude];
    self.lblLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude  %f", [location coordinate].longitude];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    self.lblLatitude.text = [error description];
    self.lblLongitude.text = nil;
}
```